# Hide/Show Conditional Formatting Data Bar

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a Conditional Formatting Data Bar showing % of task completion, however Excel seems to ignore this conditional formula position 
on my Conditional Formatting layers, as Data Bar appears on top any other formatting I am trying to apply.

What I would like to do is to hide/turn off Data Bar and cell text, if Status cell next to it contains text “Closed”. 
I managed to hide the text using Custom Format “;;;” in formatting, however Data Bar is on top of any other formatting I am trying to apply.

Example below

[image: Show Bar]
[image: Hide Bar]

Data Bar Conditional Formatting settings used

[image: Data Bar Formatting]
[image: Conditional Formatting layers]

Status Column "override" formatting settings (hide text using ;;; and apply cell fill colour)

[image: Top formatting]
[image]

Please help. Thanks

Comment: How are you populating the cell? Do you have a formula in the cell or are you typing the value straight into the cell?

Comment: Mark "Stop if True" for the first rule that will override all other settings.

Comment: Click on Manage Rules and with your second Conditional Formatting Rule which checks for Closed, check the Checkbox for Stop If True. See if that resolves your issue.

Comment: @Zac I type there values by hand. No formulas.

Comment: @Hellboy that's it! :D It is working now :D Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Stop if true" option on the first Conditional Formatting Rule stoped execution of below Data Bar rule.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking this box? [image]

Comment: Tried just now, it has no effect

Comment: Sorry, went back to read your question (it's so thorough and filled with images that it becomes quite difficult to read). Seems like you want to use "Stop if true" in conditional formatting manager, as other commenters have pointed out.

Comment: is solved the problem. Stop if true worked like a charm. Thanks!